# Multiple Toggle Switches on page CSS

Tags: html, css, toggle

I am trying to recreate multiple `toggle` switches on one page but when I create a new switch it doesn't work and it controls the 1st switch that I created. The `toggle` switch that I am trying make is like an on and off switch like on the iPhone. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqmrL3ym/)

```css
.switch {
  font: 16px"adiHaus-Bold", Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  border-top: #CCC solid 1px;
  border-bottom: #EEE solid 1px;
  border-right: #ddd solid 1px;
  border-left: #ddd solid 1px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 130px;
  margin: .2em;
  @include border-radius(3px);
  @include background-clip(padding-box);
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  @include background-image(linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, .07) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .07) 100%));
}
.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: left;
  width: 63px;
  line-height: 42px;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #CDCDCD;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.switch-label-off {
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #FFFFFF;
}
.switch-label-on {
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #FFFFFF;
}
.switch-input {
  display: none;
}
.switch-input:checked + .switch-label {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -moz-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -ms-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -o-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
}
.switch-input:checked + .switch-label-on ~ .switch-selection {
  left: 65px;
}
.switch-selection {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 63px;
  height: 38px;
  @include border-radius(2px);
  @include background-clip(padding-box);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -moz-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -ms-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -o-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
}
label,
.form-label-text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<span class="form-title">Hand:</span>
<div class="switch">
  <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view" value="one" id="one" checked>
  <label for="one" class="switch-label switch-label-off">L</label>
  <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view" value="two" id="two">
  <label for="two" class="switch-label switch-label-on">R</label>
  <span class="switch-selection"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are applying the same classes for both, so when you use `:checked`, it will slide just the 1st.

Assign ID's to each `input`

**Note**

And you are missing a closing `div`

```css
.switch {
  font: 16px"adiHaus-Bold", Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  border-top: #CCC solid 1px;
  border-bottom: #EEE solid 1px;
  border-right: #ddd solid 1px;
  border-left: #ddd solid 1px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 130px;
  margin: .2em;
  border-radius:3px;
  background-clip:padding-box;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  background-image:linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, .07) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .07) 100%);
}
.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: left;
  width: 63px;
  line-height: 42px;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #CDCDCD;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.switch-label-off {
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #FFFFFF;
}
.switch-label-on {
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #FFFFFF;
}
.switch-input {
  display: none;
}
#one:checked + .switch-label,
#three:checked + .switch-label {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -moz-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -ms-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -o-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
}
#one ~.switch-input:checked + .switch-label-on ~ .switch-selection,
#three ~.switch-input:checked + .switch-label-on ~ .switch-selection {
  left: 65px;
}
.switch-selection {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 63px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius:2px;
  background-clip:padding-box;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -moz-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -ms-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -o-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.820, 0.165, 1.000);
}
label,
.form-label-text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<span class="form-title">Hand:</span>
<div class="switch">
  <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view" value="one" id="one" checked>
  <label for="one" class="switch-label switch-label-off">L</label>
  <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view" value="two" id="two">
  <label for="two" class="switch-label switch-label-on">R</label>
  <span class="switch-selection"></span>
</div>
<hr />

<span class="form-title">Hand:</span>
<div class="switch">
  <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view" value="three" id="three" checked>
  <label for="three" class="switch-label switch-label-off">L</label>
  <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view" value="four" id="four">
  <label for="four" class="switch-label switch-label-on">R</label>
  <span class="switch-selection"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help mate!

Comment: Hey, when I made the buttons they switch back and forth when one is selected. Example: I can't have both of the buttons selected. When I select the top R and then select the bottom R the top R button slides back to the left.